# Trouble running multiple simulators with XCode

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm running XCode 8 and I've followed a few of the resources to run multiple simulators but, unfortunately, whenever I compile the code within XCode, it restarts all of the simulators to the same exact version and crashes all except for the primary that's displaying the application.

My approach was the `open -n Simulator.app` where I open up multiple simulators manually and then target the various devices within XCode.

Any better solutions out there?

Comment: Running multiple simulators is not supported on Xcode 8 & earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9 supports this out of the box, I would recommend that you upgrade unless you have a specific reason not to do this.

Comment: I can't upgrade, unfortunately, as I need to run an older version of OSX